# How to make desktop application remeber user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, database, electron

Alright, so I'm working on a new project of mine. It's basically a launcher/hub for .exe programs. So I want each user to be able to add their desired .exe programs to the launcher. But how do I make it so that the launcher remembers each users input for the next time they open the launcher? Do I need to setup and connect to a database for this? 
I am writing this software in HTML/CSS/JAVASRIPT through Electron forge + NodeJS. 
Thanks for time and help.

Comment: Is this a local application? As in, data that 1 user stores doesn't need to be accessible by another user? If so, you could use something like [electron-settings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-settings) to store a JSON array of the users "settings" (desired .exe programs) which can be loaded each time the program is ran.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes exaclty! Local, so that you won't be able to see what programs i've added and i won't see yours. I will look into your tip right away, thank you kind sir :)